# Clipping a rotating SVG to text in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, clip-path

I have an SVG image of a [starburst pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49aaz.jpg) that is rotating using a `transform: rotate` animation, and a text element next to it. Whenever the brighter part of the starburst overlaps the text, I want that part of the text to change color. Basically, the starburst should clip to the text while rotating.

The basic setup is:

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="starburst-image">
        <img src="starburst-dark.svg" class="starburst"></img>
        <img src="starburst-bright.svg" class="starburst starburst-bright"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="title-wrapper">
        <h1 class="title-text">Title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, the two `starburst` images have `position: absolute`, perfectly coincide with each other, and are both rotating using a CSS animation. The entirety of `starburst-dark` should show up in the background without clipping, while the `starburst-bright` should clip to the `title-text` while it rotates.

I can't seem to get the SVG to both rotate and clip to the text, after playing with properties like `clip-path` and `background-clip`. I also tried putting the text in an svg `<text>` element instead of `<h1>` and wrapping it in a `<clipPath>`, but it seemed like the text clip was then positioned relative to the coordinates of the starburst SVG rather than the coordinates of the title text itself.

There must be some way to do this in HTML/CSS, right?

Comment: You state _overlaps the text .. that part of the text to change color_ but you also say _the starburst should clip to the text_.  Which do you  want?  It would seem that these two effects would be mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want so both, but separately?

The clipping is not actually clipped. It is just covered over.

```css
body {
    width: 1000px;
}

img.change {
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 160px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;

    animation:rotate 8s linear infinite;

    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

img.clip {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;

    animation:rotate 8s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

div.change,
div.clip {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: green;
}

div.clip {
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: -800px;
    left: 700px;
    width: 400px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

h1 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Rotating starburst changing colour of text</h1>
<div class="change">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<img class="change" src='data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 800 800">
<path fill="gold" d="M 280 0 L 520 0 L 400 400 Z" />
<path fill="gold" d="M 0 400 L 400 400 L 0, 160 Z" />
<path fill="gold" d="M 800 400 L 400 400 L 800, 160 Z" />
<path fill="gold" d="M 0 800 L 0 540 L 400 400 L 280 800 Z" />
<path fill="gold" d="M 800 800 L 800 640 L 400 400 L 520 800 Z" />
</svg>' />
<div class="change">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<h1>Text "clipping" rotating starburst</h1>
<img class="clip" src='data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 800 800">
<path fill="gold" d="M 280 0 L 520 0 L 400 400 Z" />
<path fill="gold" d="M 0 400 L 400 400 L 0, 160 Z" />
<path fill="gold" d="M 800 400 L 400 400 L 800, 160 Z" />
<path fill="gold" d="M 0 800 L 0 540 L 400 400 L 280 800 Z" />
<path fill="gold" d="M 800 800 L 800 640 L 400 400 L 520 800 Z" />
</svg>' />
<div class="clip">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</body>
```

[EDIT 20221206 Added combined dual rotating starbursts and title]

In the coding below I have separated the two starburst only to see the effect working better. To combined change the img.dark left back to 100px.

```css
body {
    width: 1000px;
}

div.container {
    min-height: 900px;
    position: relative;
    top: 300px;
}

div.bright {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: 100px;
    
    clip-path: inset(175px -170px -170px -170px);
}

img.bright {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;

    animation:rotate 12s linear infinite;

}

img.dark {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;

    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: 130px;

    z-index: -1;

    animation:rotate 12s linear infinite;

}

@keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Dark rotating starburst as background to title with bright rotating starburst (seemingly) clipped by title</h1>
    <div class="bright">
    <img class="bright" src='data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 800 800">
    <path fill="gold" d="M 280 0 L 520 0 L 400 400 Z" />
    <path fill="gold" d="M 0 400 L 400 400 L 0, 160 Z" />
    <path fill="gold" d="M 800 400 L 400 400 L 800, 160 Z" />
    <path fill="gold" d="M 0 800 L 0 640 L 400 400 L 280 800 Z" />
    <path fill="gold" d="M 800 800 L 800 640 L 400 400 L 520 800 Z" />
    </svg>' />
    </div>
    <img class="dark" src='data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 800 800">
    <path fill="brown" d="M 0 0 L 0 160 L 400 400 L 280 0 Z" />
    <path fill="brown" d="M 520 0 L 800 0 L 800 160 L 400 400 Z" />
    <path fill="brown" d="M 0 400 L 400 400 L 0 640 Z" />
    <path fill="brown" d="M 800 400 L 800 640 L 400 400 Z" />
    <path fill="brown" d="M 400 400 L 280 800 L 520 800 Z" />
    </svg>' />
</div>
</body>
```

Please advise if you need something more/else.